# update data inside a scroller asynchronously in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I am adding data inside a VGroup dynamically using Action Script. Each data is an instance of a custom component. So when the number of item is more, It take time to load, which look bad.

Is there any way, we can load data to it, asynchronously or is there any way, so that more data can be added inside a scroller only when the scroll bar reaches to the end (as it happens in Android or IPhone).?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `<s:List>` component and create [your own item renderer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS03d33b8076db57b9-23c04461124bbeca597-8000.html) for it. You can also go for a hack-a-thlon and write your own implementation of `VGroup`, where it will load only the currently displayed items, but that's what `<s:List>` does, anyway.

Comment: I agree... List with vertical layout